# One design in five sizes and multiple colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, artboard, multiple-sizes

So I'm working on a set of documents that will be printed in 5 sizes and 20 color combinations (design consists of just two colors).

What's the best way to setup a document in Adobe Illustrator CS6, so I can have the best results. Best result for me would be that once I save the document, I have it in 5 sizes, 20 color combinations each, 100 files total. Is it too much? I'm thinking it could be done with artboards, at least the 20 color combinations, but with the sizes it would be perfect.

Any help welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me...

- 1 file per color
- 5 artboards per file.
- use **global** colors

To change colors, copy the file, open it, double-click the Global color swatch... change color... BAM all colors change ... save as new color version. I would also link .ai files to .ai files to keep content centrally located. So I could edit content, update links... and the subsequent files update as well.

I, personally, would not put everything in one file.

Worst case, if you need to edit the text (content) later, Edit one file.. repeat the steps to change color and create new files.

This is really all *opinion-based*. Others will certainly have their preferred workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try something similar as you suggested. Though I don't know whether messing with global colors would affect color profiles. I have settings for the printer that I'll be using, so don't want to mess things up. Maybe just manually change color for 5 artboards.

Comment: @Jimi Global swatches merely changes how the **swatches work** it doesn't alter any color profiles.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this one up, it will make things a lot easier now.